# type or namespace wwwroot does not exist

Tags: .net

I have a dotnet core webapp and im tryng to create a razor page , but when i build the project i get wwwroot does not exist...is just a simple razor page. I have added the the start up the app.UseStaticFiles();. Any ideas what im missing?

```
@page
@using MRV.ServicoEmail.wwwroot.Templates.Email
@model MRV.ServicoEmail.wwwroot.Templates.Email.Extrato

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: structure]

Comment: can you please share your solution file system structure ?

Comment: Ok, edited the question with it